# How to modify PagedList data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Hy

I have a problem, in my app.

I would like to get a list inside an inner list from database, which would be easy, if I wouldn't want to filter the inner list.

I found a possible solution, but it isn't work, because I get a FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_1 because of int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

As you can see, there is a crmLeadActivities list inside CrmOpAc, and I wan't to filter crmLeadActivities    by Date

```
This is my object, I think the properties doesn't matter 

class CrmOpAc(
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "oid",
        entityColumn = "crm_opportunity_oid"
    )
    var crmLeadActivities: List<CrmLeadActivity> = emptyList()
): CrmOpportunity()


Custom datasource: 
abstract class CustomRelation<Model>(
    private val roomDatabase: RoomDatabase,
    private val query: SupportSQLiteQuery,
    vararg val tables: String
) : DataSource.Factory<Int, Model>() {

    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Model> {
        return object : LimitOffsetDataSource<Model>(roomDatabase, query, true, *tables) {

            // never called
            override fun convertRows(cursor: Cursor?): MutableList<Model>? = null

            override fun loadRange(startPosition: Int, loadCount: Int): MutableList<Model> {
                Timber.d("Lista")
                Timber.d("Lista ${loadCount.toString()}")
                roomDatabase.beginTransaction()
                try {
                    val list: MutableList<Model> =
                        queryData(loadCount, startPosition).toMutableList()

                    roomDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful()
                    return list
                } finally {
                    roomDatabase.endTransaction()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract fun queryData(loadCount: Int, startPosition: Int): List<Model>
}

repository fun:

    fun getProjectWithEvent2(
        searchText: String
    ): LiveData<PagedList<CrmOpAc>> {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        val bindLists = ArrayList<Any>()

        sb.append("SELECT * FROM ${CrmOpportunity.TABLE_NAME} WHERE short_name like ? ")
        bindLists.add(searchText)

        val simpleSqLiteQuery = SimpleSQLiteQuery(sb.toString(), bindLists.toTypedArray())

        return LivePagedListBuilder(object :
            CustomRelation<CrmOpAc>(appDatabase, simpleSqLiteQuery, "crm_opportunities","crm_lead_activities") {

            override fun queryData(
                loadCount: Int,
                startPosition: Int
            ): List<CrmOpAc> {

                val list  = crmOpportunityDao.getProjectWithEvents2(simpleSqLiteQuery)
                
                // TODO filter by date
                list.forEach {
                    it.crmLeadActivities = crmOpportunityDao.getCrmActivities(it.oid)
                }

                return list
            }
        }, 10).build()
    }
```

Update:
This was my first solution, but unfortunately it didn't work. I filtered theese CrmOpportunity which contains just those CrmLeadActivites which dates fits by filter.
But the final result was wrong, because room put all CrmLeadActivities to the inner list.

```
fun getProjectWithEvent(
        searchText: String, fromDate: Long,
        toDate: Long
    ): LiveData<PagedList<CrmOpportunityWithEventsView>> {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        val bindLists = ArrayList<Any>()

        sb.append("SELECT t1.* , count(t2.oid) FROM ${CrmOpportunity.TABLE_NAME} t1 LEFT JOIN ${CrmLeadActivity.TABLE_NAME} t2 ON t1.oid = t2.crm_opportunity_oid WHERE (t1.short_name like ? ")
        bindLists.add(searchText)
        sb.append(" OR t2.subject like ? ) ")
        bindLists.add(searchText)

        sb.append(" AND t2.start_on >= ? ")
        bindLists.add(fromDate)
        sb.append(" AND t2.start_on <= ? ")
        bindLists.add(toDate)

        sb.append(" GROUP BY t1.oid HAVING count(t2.oid) > 0 ORDER BY t1.oid")

        val simpleSqLiteQuery = SimpleSQLiteQuery(sb.toString(), bindLists.toTypedArray())

        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .setPageSize(50)
            .setPrefetchDistance(50)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(50 * 2).build()

        return LivePagedListBuilder(
            crmOpportunityDao.getProjectWithEvents(simpleSqLiteQuery),
            config
        ).build()
    }
```

Comment: What is stopping you from creating a query that does this for you upfront `ORDER BY` etc..?  Post filtering data in memory is "usually" far more expensive and gives you another point of failure shoud the final data be wrong.

Comment: You are right, but it isn't solve my problem. Firstly I created a native query and I filtered the inner list, and the result wasn't good, although I get theese CrmOpportunity which contains crmLeadActivities filtered by date, but in the final result there was crmLeadActivities which didn't fit the filter

Comment: you must not modify the paged list data. Each paged list is coming from pagedlist/datasource pair. Please create a new datasource to provide new data with the specified filter

Comment: @PhúcNguyễn yes and no - you can infact use operators like :`mapby` and `mapPageBy` - any differences in dataset size and ordering (i.e. modyfing the list, not item content) would definitely break the pagination however.

Comment: Pagination doesn't matter in this case, ther won't be a lot of data, maybe 10-15 row, but I have to use, because I use an abstract fragment, which use pagination